# move_uploaded_file not working when uploading more than one files - Intermittently

Tags: php

**What I need**

I need to upload three files to the some directory at the same time and update MySQL database

**The problem**

Sometimes files can upload. But sometimes not all files uploading. Lets say I have file A, B and C. Sometimes all A, B and C can upload. But sometimes randomly (Either A, B or C) some files not uploading. But the MySQL query always update correctly. No issue with that

**Codes**

Following are my codes. Anyone can spot any mistakes? or any better way of doing this?

```html
if($cadguiUpdated == 'cadYes' && $excelSheetUpdated == 'excelYes' && $tpi == 'tpiYes') {  
        
        mkdir($pathCad, 0, true);
        mkdir($pathExcel, 0, true);
        mkdir($pathTpi, 0, true);

        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileCad"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileCad);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileExcel"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileExcel);
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileTpi"]["tmp_name"], $target_fileTpi);
        
        

       $sql="INSERT INTO dbtuts.tbl_uploads(prjId, date, cadFile, cadType,cadUpdate, cadTempPerm, cadRevision, cadRemarks, cadRemarksHistory, excelFile, excelType, excelUpdate, excelTempPerm, excelRevision, excelRemarks, excelRemarksHistory, tpiFile, tpiType, tpiUpdate, tpiRevision, tpiRemarks, tpiRemarksHistory, optionalRemarks, updatedPerson, activity) VALUES('$prjId','$updatedDate', '$save_fileCad','$fileTypeCad','$cadguiUpdated','$tempPermCad', '$revisionCad', '$cadguiRemarks','$cadInitialRemarks', '$save_fileExcel','$fileTypeExcel','$excelSheetUpdated','$tempPermExcelSheet', '$revisionExcelSheet', '$excelSheetRemarks','$excelInitialRemarks', '$save_fileTpi','$fileTypeTpi','$tpi', '$formNumber', '$tpiRemarks','$tpiInitialRemarks', '$optionalRemarks', '$updatedPerson', '$activity')";
       mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        

echo '<br><div class=" container alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade in"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a><strong>Success </strong>: Successfully created</div>';

        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried many things, finally realised issue was due to file size. Sometimes the files I used to upload was too big compared to the declared file size. To change allowed upload file size limit I did few changes in php.ini file.

**Step 1**

Open php.ini file and search for this string `upload_max_filesize`. Change this to your preferred value.

**Step 2**

Search for `post_max_size` in the php.ini file and change it according to your desired value. Take note that, this post_max_size is the file size before you actually upload it.

Initially I did only Step 1. But still couldn't upload due to `post_max_size` was not set correctly. After did Step 2, I am able to upload files without any issue for the specified file size

**NB: Please make sure to restart your XAMPP after do the changes.**